# r facet_wrap not grouping properly with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm struggling with facet_wrap in R. It should be simple however the facet variable is not being picked up? Here is what I'm running:

```
plot = ggplot(data = item.household.descr.count, mapping = aes(x=item.household.descr.count$freq, y = item.household.descr.count$descr, color = item.household.descr.count$age.cat)) + geom_point() 
plot = plot + facet_wrap(~ age.cat, ncol = 2)
plot
```

[image: resulting plot]

I colored the faceting variable to try to help illustrate what is going on. The plot should have only one color in each facet instead of what you see here. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: what's in `item.household.descr.count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused by fact that you are using `$`and data frame name to refer to your variables inside the `aes()`. Using `ggplot()` you should only use variables names in `aes()` as data frame is named already in `data=`.

```
plot = ggplot(data = item.household.descr.count, 
                mapping = aes(x=freq, y = descr, color = age.cat)) + geom_point() 
plot = plot + facet_wrap(~ age.cat, ncol = 2)
plot
```

Here is an example using diamonds dataset.

```
diamonds2<-diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),1000),]

ggplot(diamonds2,aes(diamonds2$carat,diamonds2$price,color=diamonds2$color))+geom_point()+
          facet_wrap(~color)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(diamonds2,aes(carat,price,color=color))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've been beating my head off the wall trying to sort this out for a while.