# Wrong grouping with facet_wrap and geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Pair,Total readNUM,Uniquely mapped readNUM,Batch
CP3027_merged_trimmed,83750278,75237898,P160411
CP3028_merged_trimmed,94621036,86736510,P160411
CP3029_merged_trimmed,89051500,80999978,P160411
CP3030_merged_trimmed,100399436,89787060,P160411
CP3032_merged_trimmed,91591620,83432242,P160411
CP3036_merged_trimmed,81272998,73541686,P160411
CP3037_merged_trimmed,85289630,77513350,P160411
CP3058_merged_trimmed,85092730,78269348,P160411
CP3059_merged_trimmed,81696100,74981834,P160411
CP3060_merged_trimmed,88098518,79513000,P160411
CP3065_merged_trimmed,75924870,68052566,P160411
CP3066_merged_trimmed,89746438,79933004,P160411
CP3068_merged_trimmed,82041060,73183314,P160411
CP3074_merged_trimmed,82162078,74321554,P160411
CP3078_merged_trimmed,77500516,70835090,P160411
CP3185_merged_trimmed,99023950,90729150,P160411
CP3081_trimmed,88044290,76494036,P160475
CP3084_trimmed,88741718,79056712,P160475
CP3085_trimmed,81212190,71851198,P160475
CP3091_trimmed,82675822,72460250,P160475
CP3092_trimmed,96965168,86268756,P160475
CP3093_trimmed,68717952,60125000,P160475
CTL001_trimmed,74160410,63648530,P160475
CTL004_trimmed,100474172,85822840,P160475
CP1950_trimmed,162963640,136601638,SO41314
CP2160_trimmed,77991138,65584038,SO41314
CP2171_trimmed,89296686,75887918,SO41314
CP2204_trimmed,71691448,60311650,SO41314
CP2325_trimmed,95803886,80002310,SO41314
CP3133_trimmed,76307744,64964436,SO41314
CP3249_trimmed,78904062,67382812,SO41314
CP3541_trimmed,67020194,56703314,SO41314
CP0678_trimmed,19986550,18575050,SBSQ8092_1
CP2032_trimmed,21722580,20138926,SBSQ8092_1
CP2164_trimmed,23275750,21359668,SBSQ8092_1
CP2544_trimmed,22376982,20652410,SBSQ8092_1
CP2695_trimmed,22264402,20631472,SBSQ8092_1
CP3127_trimmed,33050232,29990758,SBSQ8092_2
CP3141_trimmed,24164170,21655048,SBSQ8092_2
CP2997_trimmed,96381034,91772686,NG-10002
L0218_001_trimmed,257181636,81639268,x
L0218_002_trimmed,263258410,31357342,x
L0218_003_trimmed,183642720,30657224,x
```

For every sample (Pair = col 1), I plotted the total number of reads (col 2) over the mapped reads (col 3) and coloured the bars by experiment (col 4).
The result is shown in Figure 1:
[image: Figure 1]

The samples are not ordered,making difficult to compare samples belonging to the same experiment (batch).
To make the plot more readable, I grouped them by experiment using `facet_wrap`.

[image: Figure 2]

The resulting plot (Figure 2) has the correct colouring, but the samples are not placed in the right groups by `facet_wrap` (or `facet_grid`).

In a different post ("[r facet_wrap not grouping properly with geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105895/r-facet-wrap-not-grouping-properly-with-geom-point)"[stackover link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105895/r-facet-wrap-not-grouping-properly-with-geom-point)) it was suggested to avoid using the `$` to refer to the variables inside `aes()`.
I then modify the code (`BamSummaryRaw$Pair -> Pair` and `BamSummaryRaw$Batch -> Batch`), but the issue persists.

This is the code I used:

```
library(ggplot2);library(cowplot);library(grid)
library(gridExtra);library(reshape2)

BamSummaryRaw <- read.table('BamSummary_B38.csv',header=T,sep=',',quote='',check.names=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# convert # in millions
totReadsMill <- BamSummaryRaw$`Total readNUM`/1000000
totMappedMill <- BamSummaryRaw$`Uniquely mapped paired readNUM`/1000000

experiments <- BamSummaryRaw$Batch

# plots
gg.MAIN <- ggplot(BamSummaryRaw,aes(x=Pair,fill=experiments))

gg.reads <- gg.MAIN + geom_bar(aes(y=totReadsMill),fill='white',colour='black',stat='identity',width = 0.5,show.legend = T) +
   geom_bar(aes(y=totMappedMill),colour='black',stat='identity',width = 0.5,show.legend = T) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1,size=5)) +
   labs(x='samples',y='# of reads [10^6]') +
   ylim(0,200)

#prova <- gg.reads + facet_grid(~BamSummaryRaw$Batch,scales='free_x', labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line=FALSE))
prova <- gg.reads + facet_wrap(~Batch,scales='free_x',nrow=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly all you need is to order x-axis. You can do this with `scale_x_discrete()`. Just pass vector of samples to function and x-axis will be sorted according it.

```
# Using OPs data
# Rename for easier manipulation
colnames(BamSummaryRaw) <- c("pair", "total", "mapped", "batch")

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(BamSummaryRaw, aes(pair, fill = batch)) +
    # Number of total reads (M)
    geom_bar(aes(y = total / 1e6), fill = "white", color = "black",
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    # Number of mapped reads (M)
    geom_bar(aes(y = mapped / 1e6), color = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    # Order x-axis
    scale_x_discrete(limits = BamSummaryRaw$pair) +
    # Add labels
    labs(title = "Number of reads",
         subtile = "Total and Mapped / Grouped per batch",
         x = NULL,
         y = "Number of reads, M",
         fill = "Batch") +
    # Nicer theme
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Another way to represent NGS stats would be to plot percentage of mapped reads with:

```
ggplot(BamSummaryRaw, aes(pair, fill = batch)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = mapped * 100 / total), color = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = BamSummaryRaw$pair) +
    labs(title = "Percentage of mapped reads",
         subtile = "Total and Mapped / Grouped per batch",
         x = NULL,
         y = "Mapped, %",
         fill = "Batch") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.
It works and your code is much cleaner than mine, but I would still try to understand why `facet_wrap` is not grouping properly.
Regarding your second point, I do agree with you, but in this specific case I really need to work with numbers of reads rather than percentages.
In this way I can spot sample contaminations much easier.

Comment: @fra Problem in your case is this line: `gg.MAIN <- ggplot(BamSummaryRaw,aes(x=Pair,fill=experiments))` change `fill=experiments` to `fill=Batch`. `experiments` in not in `BamSummaryRaw` data.frame and while it's possible to pass vectors to `ggplot2` from my personal experience - it's never a good idea (almost always messes something up). Let me know how it goes

Comment: @fra also `aes(y=totReadsMill)`. **Don't** pass vectors - will mess up your results

Comment: replacing `experiments` with `batch` (as the other post suggested) solved the issue also in my original code. I tried to remove `experiments` before, but it wasn't working because I was still passing vectors later on. Thanks

Comment: @fra you can accept the answer if it helped to solve your problem